# Sql Query in C# Distinct Value and Max Date Join Two Tables

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently trying to get account number from one table, accountinfo, and find a max date for that account from another table, fup.

I'm new at both sql and c# so any help would be awesome!

So far I have

```
Select max(FUP.FA_TDATE), accountinfo.account 
from accountinfo 
inner join fup on accountinfo.account = fa_classaccount
```

I need this to return the max date and then the account.

Comment: So swap the two. `accountinfo.account, max(FUP.FA_TDATE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Group By` when using an aggregate function like `MAX()`

```
Select max(FUP.FA_TDATE), accountinfo.account 
from accountinfo 
inner join fup on accountinfo.account = fup.fa_classaccount
GROUP BY accountinfo.account
```